# How do I make a HTML/CSS element disappear after a jQuery animation completes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this animation where a box moves from one part of the page to another with the click of a start button.

How would I get the box to disappear from the page after the animation is completed?

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      left: $(window).width() - 800
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <p> BOX </p>
</div>
<div id="box">
  <p> Box </p>
</div>
<button>Start</button>
```

Comment: An ID must be unique in a document

Comment: jQuery's `animate` takes a callback function as an optional argument. That's a fancy way to say, you can optionally add a function to run once `animate` call completes. See [jQuery doc page here](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

You can run this right now, just add the complete event and it worked.
Also read about [.animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> edited: Update Jquery to version 3.6.0

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      left: $(window).width() - 800
    },{
      complete: function () { // complete call back
        $("#box").hide(); // can hide or remove this elemenet
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box">
  <p> Box </p>
</div>

<style type='text/css'>
  #box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
  }
</style>

<button>Start</button>
```

Comment: jQuery 3.3.1 was released in 2018 [and has known XSS vulnerabilities](https://snyk.io/test/npm/jquery/3.3.1). Is there a reason your snippet isn't using the latest 3.6.0 version?

Comment: @Dai possibly as that is the highest one currently available in the Snippet Editor

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Dai Sorry I was in a hurry and forgot to update jquery to the latest version. Now it latest

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      left: $(window).width() - $("#box").width()
    }, function() {
      $("#box").fadeOut();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <p>BOX</p>
</div>
<button>Start</button>
```

With `.animate()`, you can pass in an anonymous function to use once the animation is complete. I opted to use `.fadeOut()` to Hide the element. There are many ways to do this.

Please see:

- https://api.jquery.com/animate/
- https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/